# How to set header Authentication in httpRequest?

Tags: java, json, header, authorization, httprequest

How to set header Authentication in httpRequest?

I tried with this, but It didn't work well.

```
 connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
 connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", accesToken);
 connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work well"?

Comment: If your server-side app is Asp.Net WebAPI, use connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesToken);. If others, I think will be connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + accesToken);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I do for HTTP request with Basic Authentication:

```java
String pageUrl ="http://......";
String username = "yourUsername";
String password = "yourPassword";

HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
int timeoutConnection = 10000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeoutConnection);
int timeoutSocket = 10000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeoutSocket);

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(pageUrl);
String credential = Base64.encodeToString( (username+":"+password).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + credential.substring(0, credential.length()-1));
httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpGet.setHeader("Connection", "close");
                            
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();               
if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    httpResponse.getEntity().writeTo(outputStream);
    String responseString = outputStream.toString();
    System.out.println(responseString);
    // ......  // proceeding operations             
}
```